# Change the Theme in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: themes, editor, jupyter-notebook

I like dark themes. However, the default theme of Jupyter notebooks is light, and I can't find the option to change the theme/background-color. How is this done?

Comment: using conda: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyterthemes

Comment: Use JupyterLab: Settings -> JupyterLab Theme -> JupyterLab Dark

Answer (score 680, accepted):

This is easy to do using the `jupyter-themes` package by Kyle Dunovan. You may be able to install it using `conda`. Otherwise, you will need to use `pip`.

Install it with conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes
```

or pip:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

You can get the list of available themes with:

```
jt -l
```

So change your theme with:

```
jt -t theme-name
```

To load a theme, finally, reload the page. The docs and source code are [here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes). When setting a theme, optionally also specify `-T` (`--toolbar`) in the same command to also retain the toolbar, without which the toolbar is not shown. For help, type `jt -h`.

Comment: Note - I had to restart the jupyter server for this to work.

Comment: For the first time one **may** need to restart the `jupyter notebook` for this to work, but next time, simply just change `jt -t <themes>` on terminal and reload the notebook pages. It behaves something like this to me.

Comment: how to reset to default theme?

Comment: `jupyterthemes` is not on conda neither on conda-forge, the only way to install it is through `pip` only

Comment: I did succeed with conda after adding conda-forge channel  `conda config --add channels conda-forge`

Comment: When I try this I get an error: `Cannot uninstall 'pyzmq'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: Crashed the SPARKMAGIC extension - also got these errors in the terminal - also totally crashed the iPyKernel functionality ----     [W 09:35:15.695 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/     [W 09:35:26.867 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?

Comment: If `jupyterthemes` is on conda-forge the answer should be `conda install jupyterthemes -c conda-forge

Comment: I installed jupyterthemes using pip but when I run jt -t, I got `bash: jt: command not found`

Comment: @user1801605 sounds like a problem with your environment. Have you activated the correct one - if that doesn't solve your issue please open a new question specifying where pip installs packages on your system and if you are using venv/conda.

Comment: This library `jupyterthemes` has a ton of dependencies. It seems too much just changing the color of the theme, is there any other options?

Comment: Thank you so much :)
I restarted Jupyter notebook and then it worked as expected.

Comment: could be noted that `jt -r`  could reset the theme to default,    and no need to restart the server , just refresh the Jupiter URL is okay.

Comment: If it says 'name 'jt' is not defined' then you can try !jt instead: https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/92#issuecomment-430108540

Comment: For Dark mode graphs/charts. use this 
```
from jupyterthemes import jtplot
jtplot.style(theme='monokai', context='notebook', ticks=True, grid=False);
```

Comment: Also worth noting, after installation and restart of `jupyter notebook` one can easily switch the theme from within the notebook via `!jt -t <theme>`

Comment: this doesn't work for jupyter lab. How can i import one of these themes in jupyter lab?

Comment: Might be obvious, but for those who are doing this on a running notebook(Jupyter):`!pip install jupyterthemes` (*basically, set a ! in front of pip*)

Comment: How to go back to default theme, is monaki the default one

Comment: use !jt -l to list themes and refresh the page, no need to restart the kernel or server

Comment: Installed! 
But where are the options buttons Save, Run etc. can't view them

Comment: this is awesome. 
i had to install `notebook` and then open the main page after restarting. simply reloading my notebook didn't work.

Comment: `import jupyterthemes as jt`
`from jupyterthemes.stylefx import set_nb_theme`
`set_nb_theme('chesterish')`
This works without restarting everything all the times...

Comment: Not sure this works anymore does it?  I tried it on Notebook Version: 7.0.6 and it didn't seem to work (hardly anything changed when I changed themes).

Answer (score 215):

Follow these steps

Install [`jupyterthemes`](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) with pip:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

Then choose the themes from the following and set them using the following command. Once you have installed successfully, many of us thought we need to start the jupyter server again, just refresh the page.

Set the theme with the following command:

```
jt -t <theme-name>
```

Available themes:

- onedork
- grade3
- oceans16
- chesterish
- monokai
- solarizedl
- solarizedd

Screenshots of the available themes are in its [Github repository](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/tree/master/screens).

When setting a theme, optionally also specify `-T` (`--toolbar`) in the same command to retain the toolbar, without which the toolbar is not shown. For help, type `jt -h`.

Comment: listed two things :
1. discripency against starting the jupyter server.
2. Theme conjunctions/name

Comment: This doesn't really warrant a new answer. Just a minor edit to the existing one.

Comment: There's also a chrome extension for [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jupyter-notebook-themes/aenokjighnnjpgdifpjeoebjdaehmkkn?hl=en). It basically does the same thing but without terminal interaction.

Comment: what's the name of the classic theme? If I want to revert and go back to the original classic one?

Comment: please try `jt-r`

Comment: For the sake of completeness, other than the listed themes, these 2 are also available: gruvboxd, gruvboxl as of Jan 2019

Comment: Beware this required a upgrade of both the jupyter client and tornado. So only do this if you are prepared to troubleshot the jupyter installation afterwards.

Comment: The reference to the screen shots for each theme was a very valuable addition to the question. I'm very glad this answer was here.

Comment: Refreshing the page to load a new theme doesn't work if you have `jupyter` running before installing `jupyterthemes`. In that case, just restart the server, and then refresh the page.

Comment: I tried onedork, oceans16, and chesterish. It could have something to do with my HDR TN panel monitor, but the ansi yellow background with white text for highlighting was unreadable. I had to alter the custom.css for chesterish to have the text be dark gray instead of white.

Answer (score 130):

After I changed the theme it behaved strangely. The font size was small, cannot see the toolbar and I really didn't like the new look.

For those who want to restore the original theme, you can do it as follows:

```
jt -r
```

You need to restart Jupyter the first time you do it and later refresh is enough to enable the new theme.

or directly from inside the notebook

```
!jt -r
```

Comment: thanks! i agree didnt like it and the option right below here suggesting to add dark reader to chrome instead is better

Answer (score 81):

Instead of installing a library inside Jupyter, I would recommend you use the 'Dark Reader' [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh) in Chrome (you can find 'Dark Reader' extension in other browsers, e.g. Firefox).
You can play with it; filter the URL(s) you want to have dark theme, or even how define the Dark theme for yourself.
Below are couple of examples:

[image]

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is the best approach, because we usually want dark theme which it provides and furthermore, it is easy to check the real visual of the document we are creating only by a click. (important at publish time)

Comment: Yeah... that's all good and well but the Dark Reader does not know that a jupyter notebook should color words. There's no syntax coloring, which makes this option a no-no.

Comment: @darlove, As far as I have worked with it, there is a 'syntax coloring' there (e.g. a 'for loop' syntax has the same color throughout your code.

Comment: I don't know about you, but the Dark Reader is highlighting my syntax just fine. Also this extension is a lifesaver.....finally something that can even make Stack Overflow dark!

Comment: Thanks @vladimir_putin for sharing your experience with it.

Comment: There is one issue though. If you try selecting a few characters using mouse, the selection is not visible on the black background.

Comment: I didn't like the dark themes for Jupyter and I'm loving this approach!

Comment: Dark Reader is good option, but sometimes make all code white without colours for whole notebook sheet. For example, now I have one sheet with pure white code and three sheets in colour.

Comment: I also had the issue at the beginning that the code was not highlighted or categorized. You need to **change the mode from dynamic to filter or filter+**. That changed the behaviour of the dark reader significantly.

Comment: I was getting no syntax highlighting -- all my normally-colored code appears as just white on black -- but enabled Dark Reader, went to "More", and changed to "Filter+", and now I have colored code! 
 I like this option because the other themes changed the fonts, whereas this just changes the colors.

Answer (score 44):

You can do this directly from an open notebook:

```
!pip install jupyterthemes
!jt -t chesterish
```

Restart the jupyter server for the theme's application

Comment: don't you have to restart the jupyter server for this to take effect?

Comment: True, you'll need to restart the kernel if I recall correctly

Comment: it doesn't work, you need to restart the server

Comment: This isn't working in my case. I do not have a server or anything. I run it on my local PC and save the notebooks on the harddisk. Does the same steps apply to me? And what all things do we need to do after these commands? I ran the commands and they run. The file of custom css is also created in config directory, but no change in theme.

Comment: @Meet If you run the `!jt ...` command in a notebook, refresh the browser cache with `CTRL + SHIFT + R` or `SHIFT + F5` .  (Cheat sheet for Chrome. Check under *Web page shortcuts*: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cweb-page-shortcuts). You won't have to restart anything to have the theme take effect.

Answer (score 21):

```
!pip install jupyterthemes
```

Run this library:

```py
from jupyterthemes import get_themes
import jupyterthemes as jt
from jupyterthemes.stylefx import set_nb_theme
```

and this:

```
set_nb_theme('monokai')
```

themes:

'monokai',
'chesterish',
'oceans16',
'solarizedl',
'solarizedd',
'grade3',
'onedork'

Comment: Thank you - from all the locked down corporate users who are blocked by Applocker from running arbitrary executables like jt.exe. A similar method to reset to default would help (`jt -r` equivalent). I see that deleting or blanking out custom.css is one workaround.

Comment: simple and to the point

Answer (score 18):

Simple, global change of Jupyter font size and inner & outer background colors (this change will affect all notebooks).

In Windows, find config directory by running a command:
`jupyter --config-dir`

In Linux it is `~/.jupyter`

In this directory create subfolder `custom`
Create file `custom.css` and paste:

```css
/* Change outer background and make the notebook take all available width */
.container {
    width: 99% !important;
    background: #DDC !important;
}   

/* Change inner background (CODE) */
div.input_area {
    background: #F4F4E2 !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

/* Change global font size (CODE) */
.CodeMirror {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}  

/* Prevent the edit cell highlight box from getting clipped;
 * important so that it also works when cell is in edit mode */
div.cell.selected {
    border-left-width: 1px !important;
}
```

Finally - restart Jupyter. Result:

[image: darker backgrounds]

Comment: Please, how to undo it?

Comment: Remove the file which you created (custom.css) and restart Jupyter.

Comment: It works, but I have to clear my browser cache though.

Comment: for those (like me) who wants a done ready to paste css file; (Not mine!) I tried this one and it's flawless https://raw.githubusercontent.com/powerpak/jupyter-dark-theme/master/custom.css

Answer (score 12):

## For Dark Mode Only: -

I have used Raleway Font for styling

To **C:\User\UserName\.jupyter\custom\custom.css file**

append the given styles, this is specifically for Dark Mode for jupyter notebook...

**This should be your current custom.css file: -**

```css
/* This file contains any manual css for this page that needs to override the global styles.
    This is only required when different pages style the same element differently. This is just
    a hack to deal with our current css styles and no new styling should be added in this file.*/

#ipython-main-app {
    position: relative;
}

#jupyter-main-app {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Content to be append starts now**

```css
.header-bar {
    display: none;
}

#header-container img {
    display: none;
}

#notebook_name {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}

#header-container {
    padding-left: 0px !important
}

html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: OpenSans;
}

#header {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    color: #fff;
    border: none !important
}

#menus {
    border: none !important;
    color: white !important;
}

#menus .dropdown-toggle {
    color: white !important;
}

#filelink {
    color: white !important;
    text-align: centerimportant;
    padding-left: 7px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-color: #191919 !important;
    color: #eee !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu a,
.dropdown-submenu a {
    background-color: #191919;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-default {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.dropdown {
    text-align: left !important;
}

.form-control.select-xs {
    background-color: #191919 !important;
    color: #eee !important;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#modal_indicator {
    display: none;
}

#kernel_indicator {
    color: #fff;
}

#notification_trusted,
#notification_notebook {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #eee !important;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

#logout {
    background-color: #191919;
    color: #eee;
}

#maintoolbar-container {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.notebook_app {
    background-color: #222222;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#notebook-container {
    background-color: #212121;
}

div.cell.selected,
div.cell.selected.jupyter-soft-selected {
    border: none !important;
}

.cm-keyword {
    color: orange !important;
}

.input_area {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    color: white !important;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) !important;
}

.cm-def {
    color: #5bc0de !important;
}

.cm-variable {
    color: yellow !important;
}

.output_subarea.output_text.output_result pre,
.output_subarea.output_text.output_stream.output_stdout pre {
    color: white !important;
}

.CodeMirror-line {
    color: white !important;
}

.cm-operator {
    color: white !important;
}

.cm-number {
    color: lightblue !important;
}

.inner_cell {
    border: 1px thin #eee;
    border-radius: 50px !important;
}

.CodeMirror-lines {
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.prompt.input_prompt {
    color: #5cb85c !important;
}

.prompt.output_prompt {
    color: lightblue;
}

.cm-string {
    color: #6872ac !important;
}

.cm-builtin {
    color: #f0ad4e !important;
}

.run_this_cell {
    color: lightblue !important;
}

.input_area {
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.output_png {
    background-color: white;
}

.CodeMirror-cursor {
    border-left: 1.4px solid white;
}

.box-flex1.output_subarea.raw_input_container {
    color: white;
}

input.raw_input {
    color: black !important;
}

div.output_area pre {
    color: white
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    color: white !important;
    font-weight: bolder !important;
}

.CodeMirror-gutter.CodeMirror-linenumber,
.CodeMirror-gutters {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
}


span.filename:hover {
    color: #191919 !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

#site {
    background-color: #191919 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

#tabs li.active a {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

#tabs li {
    background-color: #191919 !important;
    color: white !important;
    border-top: 1px thin #eee;
}

#notebook_list_header {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

#running .panel-group .panel {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

#accordion.panel-heading {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
}

#running .panel-group .panel .panel-heading {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: white
}

.item_name {
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.list_item:hover {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
}

.item_icon.icon-fixed-width {
    color: white !important;
}

#texteditor-backdrop {
    background-color: #191919 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

.CodeMirror {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
}

#texteditor-backdrop #texteditor-container .CodeMirror-gutter,
#texteditor-backdrop #texteditor-container .CodeMirror-gutters {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
}

.celltoolbar {
    background-color: #212121 !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

[image: Dark Mode for Jupyter Notebook]

[image: Dark Mode for Jupyter Notebook]

Comment: This answer has become obsolete in 2020.

Comment: why is it obsolete?

Answer (score 11):

Use FireFox Plug-in "**Darker Jupyter**".

Comment: Thank you, that's the right approach for me. 'jupyterthemes' all messed up on my system. (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with default fonts and Firefox)

Comment: It will work as long as Firefox is the default browser. Are there any such plugins for other browsers as well?

Answer (score 8):

You Can Follow These Steps.

1. `pip install jupyterthemes` or `pip install --upgrade jupyterthemes` to upgrade to latest version of theme.
2. after that to list all the themes you have :`jt -l`
3. after that `jt-t <themename>`for example `jt -t solarizedl`

Answer (score 7):

To install the Jupyterthemes package directly with conda, use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes
```

Then, as others have pointed out, change the theme with `jt -t <theme-name>`

Answer (score 7):

My complete solution:

1. Get Dark Reader on chrome which will not only get you a great Dark Theme for Jupyter but also for every single website you'd like (you can play with the different filters. I use Dynamic).
2. Paste those lines of code in your notebook so the legends and axes become visible:

```py
from jupyterthemes import jtplot
jtplot.style(theme='monokai', context='notebook', ticks=True, grid=False)
```

You're all set for a disco coding night !

Answer (score 5):

```
conda install jupyterthemes
```

did not worked for me in Windows. I am using Anaconda.

But,

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

worked in Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: You need to specify the right collection for conda: `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes`

Answer (score 5):

You can change themes using set_nb_theme from your running notebook

```py
!pip install jupyterthemes

from jupyterthemes import get_themes
import jupyterthemes as jt
from jupyterthemes.stylefx import set_nb_theme

set_nb_theme('chesterish')
```

pasting from https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/97540

Answer (score 5):

Another option if you're using google chrome and want a dark theme that makes working in jupyter/webpages for hours much easier on the eyes and also keeps the color scheme within your code readable is to use the "Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents" flag within experiments - chrome://flags - I usually go with the "Enabled with selective image inversion" option.

Comment: That's a cool feature - thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

With the latest version of Jupyter, you can now choose between Light and Dark themes from `Settings -> Theme`:

[image]

Works for both Jupyter Lab and Notebook.

## Note for plots

Plotting libraries are (at least as of 2023-09-24) unaware of the dark/light theme, so they will default to white. You can configure them to use dark mode with:

- Plotly:

  ```py
  import plotly.io as pio
  pio.templates.default = "plotly_dark"
  ```
- Matplotlib:

  ```py
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
  plt.style.use('dark_background')
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If there is anyone interested in running the anaconda in docker with themes enabled

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/opt/notebooks continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "pip install jupyterthemes; jt -t onedork; /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --allow-root --no-browser;"
```

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, you can install `jupyterthemes` which is more widely used.
But, I also can prefer and recommend `jupyter-themer` which is easier to use and is not effecting the default shape of `jupyter-notebook`.

Installation: `pip install jupyter-themer`

The repository with documentation and examples (*for now, examples are stored in a not merged pull-request): [@github: jupyter-thamer](https://github.com/transcranial/jupyter-themer)

My favourite customization: `jupyter-themer -b dark -c zenburn`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having an error while trying to use PIP, you can use CMD and run your commands through.