# Changed the theme in Jupyter Notebook to dark- now can't see output properly

Tags: python, themes, jupyter-notebook

[If there's an error message I can't see the start- it's really annoying.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEY5s.png)

see where there is a red arrow- the start of it is cut off. How do I fix this please?

To change the theme I followed the instructions on this thread:
[How to change the theme in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510192/how-to-change-the-theme-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: try the first answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725612/jupyter-notebook-cell-output-cut-off-truncated-by-margin-caused-by-jupyter-theme

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same issue with Jupyter Notebook. It does not support dark themes. And you can try a few codes and change the theme to dark, but the UI isn't so great.

But here's the good news! You can try "Jupyter Lab" instead of "Jupyter Notebook". It supports dark theme natively (under settings) and has a bunch of add on features as compared to Jupyter Notebook. It's just like Jupyter Notebook but way better.