# Jupyter Notebook cell output cut off/truncated by margin caused by Jupyter Themes

Tags: output, jupyter-notebook

My cell output in Jupyter Notebook is cut off on the left hand side which obscures the leftmost output. For reference (I can't post images yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEIdu.jpg

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT: Thanks to rabbit on below, the problem seems to be caused by using the alternate themes provided by Jupyter Themes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution on Jupyter Themes github page:

https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/288

"In the custom.css file, I fixed it by changing both the div.out_prompt_overlay.prompt's and the div.out_prompt_overlay.prompt:hover's min-width and width values to 11.5ex instead of the original 14.5ex."

Alternatively I added the padding:

`div.output_area {
 display: -webkit-box;
 padding: 13px;
}`

To the chesterish.css file (which was the theme I was using) and reapplied the theme using jupyter themes.

Comment: Had the same problem. Solved by upgrading package and loading my theme again.

Answer (score 0):

- Ctrl + Shift + C to open DevTools in the browser.
- go to Sources and click on static
- search for:  div.output_area
- change padding to 13px

(The developer missed 1 and put only 3px distance)

Answer (score 0):

This was raised as a bug and fixed (see https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/273). As stated by Ernest in a comment: the solution is to upgrade the package and load the theme again i.e.

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterthemes
jt -t {theme}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix the container-margins in the command line by:

`jt -m 100`

and then:

`jupyter notebook`

(100 was good for me)

Comment: This disables the theme for me