# AWS Python3 kernel dies immediately when launched

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I recently used a suggestion from [Change the Theme in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510192/change-the-theme-in-jupyter-notebook), installing jupyterthemes. It has caused the kernel to die immediately when started - how can I remove this package if I cannot run any commands through the kernel? I am working on a Jupyter notebook within Amazon Sagemaker but I am entirely new to the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new Sagemaker Notebook Instance - it will give you a clean slate to start with.