# How to change the color scheme in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to change the notebook to the dark mode such that all the extensions are kept. Also, I need that the position of the cells continued to be centered.
I tried out the solutions from other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510192/change-the-theme-in-jupyter-notebook) such

```
jt -t chesterish
```

This one removes all the extenssions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `cd ~/.jupyter`

   Go to `.jupyter` in the home dir (for example, `C:\User\metchaikovsky` or `/Users/me_tchaikovsky`)
2. `mkdir custom`

   Inside `.jupyter`, make a `dir` called `custom` (If there isn't such a dir)
3. `vi custom.css`

   Create a CSS file named `custom.css`, paste [this file](https://pastebin.com/11r6diJg) (*Pastebin may warn you about potentially offensive content, don't worry, it's just an innocent CSS file*) into `custom.css` and save it.
4. Open a new jupyter notebook and enjoy!