# How to change the default theme of Jupyter notebook?

Tags: colors, jupyter-notebook, themes

The normal version is light, is there an option to change the theme of the notebook to a different theme?

Comment: i found a similar answer

Comment: it answered my question

Comment: link: -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510192/change-the-theme-in-jupyter-notebook