# How to set jupyter notebook back to light mode

Tags: mode

I have tried going to shell and install jupyterthemes and apply jt -r. Doesn't work.

The dark theme is too dark for me. All the graph labels cannot be seen well.

Comment: Did you try `jt -t grade3` and then restart the notebook, for example? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46561480/8508004).

Comment: yes i did. several times over. I had restart , reboot.  still don't work.